# How to insert Javascript in the pages my browser is loading?

Tags: javascript, browser, squid

I have written a bunch of utility functions in Javascript that I would like to 'somehow' be able to transparently/automatically plug into the web pages served by arbitrary sites (i.e., sites I do not  control or have `root` access to).

I would like to know of at least 2 ways of achieving this. I have a vague idea that this could be done via a `squid` proxy server running locally on my (Fedora) workstation, but not sure. Because I'm on a Linux workstation, a simple, lightweight, commandline tool would also be welcome.

Comment: You want to inject javascript into a 3rd party server response?  Would that be a response to 3rd party clients, or to your own browser?  The former sounds somewhat malicious...

Comment: Greasemonkey enables you do specify scripts which are then automatically executed for specific web-sites...

Comment: @Kendrick As the title of the question says, **...my [own] browser**. I'd like to essentially insert JS in the HTML loaded by my browser.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I haven't checked out Greasemonkey yet, will later today. But from the description of it, looks like this is what I was looking for. If you can copy-paste your comment as an answer, then it will allow me to mark it as the final answer. Thanks, much. +1

Comment: @Harry sorry, I should have re-read before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) enables you do specify scripts which are then automatically executed for specific web-sites.